# Linux - hook "file_open" operation and do something with the content

Tags: linux, hook

I have some binary (blackbox for me) that has "--file" flag, in my environment setup I am not able to read any file from the harddisk, but able to write and execute anything I want.

I am looking for some way (Something simple, not like a Kernel module) to "hook" to "open" operation of the provided file, so the content will be somehow sent to me.

For example, in bash I can use `echo 1 > /dev/tcp/ip/port` to send information to tcp socket via file. But passing `/dev/tcp/ip/port` to the `--flag` argument didn't work.

Is there someway to create (for example) python script, which will be listening for an "open" operation on some file, and instead of returning a `fd` to the original file it will return a writable handle that is controlled by my python script?

Or even simplier, maybe is it possible to replace the output file handle? so I will create a file with my script and replace the `--file`'s file `fd` to mine during runtime?

Thanks!